# Implicit conversion from float 1.0833333333333333 to int loses precision-PHP-8.1

Tags: php, php-8

I am upgrading the project to  PHP 8.1 version. these two following functions are faced with warnings and caused low performance.
First function:

```
   /**
     * @param $a
     * @param $b
     * @return float
     */
    public static function div($a, $b)
    {
        return (int) ~~($a / $b);
    }
```

Second function:

```
   /**
         * @param $a
         * @param $b
         * @return mixed
         */
        public static function mod($a, $b)
        {
            return (int) $a - ~~($a / $b) * $b;
        }
```

My warning:

```
Implicit conversion from float 1.0833333333333333 to int loses precision
```

The sample used functions:

```
 public static function d2g($jdn)
    {
        $j = 4 * $jdn + 139361631;
        $j += self::div(self::div(4 * $jdn + 183187720, 146097) * 3, 4) * 4 - 3908;
        $i = self::div(self::mod($j, 1461), 4) * 5 + 308;

        $gd = self::div(self::mod($i, 153), 5) + 1;
        $gm = self::mod(self::div($i, 153), 12) + 1;
        $gy = self::div($j, 1461) - 100100 + self::div(8 - $gm, 6);

        return [$gy, $gm, $gd];
    }
```

Comment: For starters, `* @return float`, `return (int)`…?!

Comment: The full error is `Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 2.25 to int loses precision in` So its a deprecation warning telling you the blatently obvious, that if you convert a float to an int you will loose and decimal value from the result

Comment: How do you call these functions? Can you share a runnable example, along with a proper question? What kind of help are you searching for?

Comment: Worth a bit of a read https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string

Comment: I  share a runnable example

Comment: Is `~~` just a weird way of casting to int? But if so, why are you using that _and_ a proper `(int)` cast?

Answer (score 8):

The warning is quite clear: conversion of a floating point to integer results in loss of precision. As this conversion is implicit by applying the `~` operator, you get this warning.

I would suggest to use the native `intdiv` function for the first, and the `%` operator for the second function.